# How do I stop Shifting column in Pandas if index is different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `data` like this.

[image] .

I want to use `pandas` `shift` and subtract values between a `column`. This is the `code` which I am using.

```
df['Difference'] = (df['A'] - df['A'].shift(-1))
```

This is the `output` I got ( as expected).

[image]

How do I prevent `pandas` from subtracting between `columns` if the `index ( Id)` is different. I want to subtract only if the `index` is same. My desire output is something like this. Using of `df.shift(-1, axis = 0)` didn't solve either.
[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this quick & dirty with `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create Example Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'A': [6, 4, 11, 7, 9, 12]
})

# Where
df['Difference'] = np.where(
    # The Id's are the same
    df['Id'] == df['Id'].shift(-1), 
    # Take the difference
    df['A'] - df['A'].shift(-1), 
    # Else, np.NaN
    np.NaN
)
```

Output:

```
    A  Id  Difference
0   6   1         2.0
1   4   1        -7.0
2  11   1         NaN
3   7   2        -2.0
4   9   2        -3.0
5  12   2         NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

You can first `groupby` `'id'`:

```
In [156]: df.assign(
     ...:   new_col=df.groupby('id').diff(-1)
     ...: )
Out[156]: 
    A  id  new_col
0   6   1      2.0
1   4   1     -7.0
2  11   1      NaN
3   7   2     -2.0
4   9   2     -4.0
5  13   2      NaN
```

Comment: @user3280146 Glad to help.

Comment: @liliscent, great answer +1. Out of curiosity, which one would be faster? your approach or `np.where` approach suggested in other answer by @Aaron N. Brock.

Comment: @HarvIpan NumPy approach is faster. I tested just now, it's faster.

Comment: @liliscent, that's what I suspected. Thank you checking that.